# ArrayStoreException:In Generic ArrayList

Tags: java, generics

From the Java Docs of **ArrayStoreException**

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong
>   type of object into an array of objects.

To avoid this exception i used generics.But when i ran the following Test program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Number> nums = new ArrayList<Number>();
        nums.add(new Integer(1));
        nums.add(new Long(-1));
        Integer[] ints = nums.toArray(new Integer[nums.size()]);

        for (Integer integer : ints) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting `ArrayStoreException` as below - Which i am not expecting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:408)
```

Can some one help me understand why is this exception thrown even if my list is of generic type.

Comment: Method `toArray` takes array of Integers but `nums` contains Long. Long can't be cast to Integer

Answer (score 4):

Your `ArrayList` contains a `Long`. A `Long` cannot be stored in an `Integer` array, since `Integer` is not a super type of `Long`.

The following will work:

```
Number[] ints = nums.toArray(new Number[nums.size()]);

for (Number integer : ints) {
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

This is clearly stated in the Javadoc of `toArray`:

> **Throws:**
>
> ArrayStoreException - if the runtime type of the specified array is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this collection